# Any idea about the android project

Tags: android

I have covered the basics in android on the topics below:
List, Menus, Intents
Persistent Storage
Broadcasting,Notifications and Services
Locations and Maps
Telephony and Messaging. Widgets

Now, I have to develop a simple project within two weeks as part of my course. I just want to get some suggestions regarding what kind of projects can be achieved with the areas I have covered and within the timeframe.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light on that area. I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple ones:

```
* School/Class/Course Management, which is really realistic one.
* Widgets/Apps that notify/alarm your schedules, could be: class, appointments...
* Application that can detect your current location and measure distance/time if you want to go to other locations.
* Application that organize/optimize your message or whatever similar.
* File Explorer, to organize storages.
```

Well, there are many, just brainstorm and it pops like thousands.

Answer (score 1):

An old recipe: take a successful public web page/service in your country and create an app for it that works off-line/syncs the data.